# Can't Access anything in VSCode for my org after Authenticating

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli, vscode-dx

I'm setting up VScode for salesforce to change my .js-meta.xml file. After starting a project with manifest and authorizing my org I still can't see anything. I'm trying to access a already-made LWC yet nothing shows up.

I've tried right clicking on my manifest or forceapp and retrieving from source to recieve errors.

Any opinion would be appreciated, If there is anything I need to show to help other better understand the issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're having a good day.

You probably are looking for an LWC .js-meta.xml file. Can you check your package.xml file in the manifest folder if it contains the following:

```
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
```

It is required for the manifest org to retrieve Lightning web components.

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm

Comment: It does contain that.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried this: Open the package.xml file, right-click anywhere and choose " **SFDX: Retrieve Source to manifest from org** ". What results do you see in your output console then?

Comment: 'INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: use of the Metadata API requires a user with the ModifyAllData or ModifyMetadata permissions'

Comment: Probably you've your answer. The salesforce user you authenticated your org with might not have the necessary permissions. System Administrator profile is recommended. However, if you have access to edit profiles, goto setup -> users and open your user account.  Click on your profile and edit. Search "Modify All Data". Allow access to this permission as well as the permission below it. Then you should be okay.